# Chrome adds whitespace to site nav but Safari does not

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, nav

I have an issue with Chrome browser adding extra whitespace to a nav link and causing it to display out of line. This is specific to Chrome as the nav displays as expected in Safari and Firefox. Here is a page with the issue https://www.mamapedia.com/n/household

Here are screen shots of the exact issue

Chrome:

[Example header in Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUoAC.png)

Safari:

[Example header in Safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDCgT.png)

This issue happens for this nav on many similar pages, but strangely not all. For example https://www.mamapedia.com/n/pregnancy displays the nav as expected in all browsers. The pages are essentially the same just different content, but the logic and css is all the same.

Does anyone know what can cause this browser specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each browser can choose how to render things, including white-space. That is why different browsers display things differently.

Try using a normalizing file such as [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make browsers more consistent.

In your case, your `<li>` tag has a bunch of white space which safari ignores and chrome displays. If you don't want to use normalize.css or it doesn't help you have two more options for your specific problem.

**Option 1:**

You can either delete the white space so it becomes `<li>Household</li>`

**Option 2:**

Or you can add a css rule to make explicitly ignore the whitespace.

The CSS rule would be:

```
li{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of cross-browser support! I highly recommend using something like normalize to prevent one off that will eventually drive you crazy.